# Junit assertions

Tags: java, junit, junit4

From a Table, I get list of String's and would like to check that when val!= "A" , a string "x" exist in the list of table :

```
for (int i = 0; i < NbRow; j++)
      {


        if (val[i] == "A")
        {
         assertFalse("");

        }
        else
        {

          list.add(myTable.getValue(j, 0)); 

          //need to check here the string exists in the list using assertTrue ?

        }
      }  

      }
```

How do I check that string X exists using assertion ?

Comment: maybe you try to re-phrase your question and define what exactly you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the strings are in a List or Set then

```
assertTrue(list.contains("rohg"));
```

Comment: what's a list ? how could I create it ?

Comment: See @Ernest's answer above. Populate the list from your table then do the assert.

Comment: I have put my code, in fact the assertion I want to do is in block else

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<NB_Row;i++){
    list.add(myTable.getValue(row,col))
}
Assert.assertTrue(list.contains("file2"));
```

Comment: I tried you solution, but I forgot to say that what I want to do is in else block , updated question above